# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: android, xml, admob

I have tried to make only a small application, but I have a problem with its layout file.

After I placed the ad in the code, my layout has been shifted, and the background too. The edittext went downer and the two buttons too. I don't know how I can make my layout to be the same after the ad place-in too. Could you help me in this please?

```
Here's the code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_ID"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />


  <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/et_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    />


 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <Button
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_post"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 <Button 
    android:text="Clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_clear"/>
 </RelativeLayout>  
 </LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: Now I could solve the layout going down problem now, but I don't know how I can make my app, that If I click on the edit text, and the keyboard is coming up, not to push away the background. Thanks for help!

Comment: can you add images of how it looks and maybe what you want?

Comment: I only want to place an AdMob ad to the top of the screen, with all of the other components staying on the same place as before. My next problem is that if I click on the edittext my background will be moved upper

Comment: "on the same place as before" - we don't know how it was before...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed your first RelativeLayout

```
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I closed it, but It didn't get better :(

Answer (score 0):

Place admob on the end of your app, if you don't want that it happens.

Comment: Is there no way to place it to top?

Comment: For sure, but it always moves your background and stuff down... you would need some thing what overlayse the add over your background. am I right?

Comment: Yes almost... In my opinion it moves my background up because I have some gradient in the background, and it will be upper than in the normal place... I don't know how I can do it better, but I would like it because my app's structure